# to draw or drawing the attention of people

Tags: grammar

A. "Firms will be invited to showcase their products, enabling them to draw the attention of our investors in attendance."

B. "Firms will be invited to showcase their products, enabling them drawing the attention of our investors in attendance."

A better or B better?

The question is when should I use "to xxx" and when should I use "xxxing" instead??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is grammatically incorrect. You can't say *enabling them drawing* because *enable* is a verb that must be followed by a verb in the infinitive form (to -verb).

Basically, when you have two verbs coming one after the other in a sentence, the second verb is either in participle form ( -ing) or in infinitive form (to -verb).

There are some verbs that allow either the infinitive or the participle form to follow them. For example, the following two sentences are correct:

> She likes **to dance** (infinitive)
>
> She likes **dancing** (participle)

What you have in your question is a verb, enable, that only allows a verb in infinitive form to follow it which is why you must say:

> Firms will be invited to showcase their products, enabling them **to draw** the attention of our investors in attendance.

Another verb that only allows infinitive verb to follow is want. So you can say:

> She wants **to buy** a new car

but you can't say:

> She wants **buying** a new car.

Unfortunately, there aren't any easy rules that you can just memorize that will tell you what form a verb should take. It's one of those things that take practice.